# only the left image is displayed on OpenGL Stereo

Tags: c++, image, visual-c++, opengl, textures

I have a problem when trying to display two images on OpenGL (Stereo Enabled with PFD_STEREO). When I try to display 2 images in the same time but, only one(last) image that's displayed and another image only shows black-color(image not shown).

Here's the code:

```
WNDCLASS wc;
HWND hWnd;
HDC hDC;
HGLRC hRC;
MSG msg;
BOOL bQuit = FALSE;

GLuint  leftImage,rightImage;

// register window class
wc.style = CS_OWNDC;
wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
wc.hInstance = hInstance;
wc.hIcon = LoadIcon( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION );
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject( BLACK_BRUSH );
wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = "GLSample";

RegisterClass( &wc );

// create main window
hWnd = CreateWindow( "GLSample", "OpenGL Texture Sample", 
WS_CAPTION | WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
0, 0, 800, 600,
NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL );

// enable OpenGL for the window
EnableOpenGL( hWnd, &hDC, &hRC );

// load our texture
leftImage = LoadTexture( "left0000.bmp", TRUE );
rightImage= LoadTexture( "right0000.bmp", TRUE );

// program main loop
while ( !bQuit ) {
    // check for messages
    if ( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) )
    {
        // handle or dispatch messages
        if ( msg.message == WM_QUIT )
        {
            bQuit = TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_LEFT);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_RIGHT);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // setup texture mapping
        glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, leftImage );

        glPushMatrix();

        glBegin( GL_QUADS );
            glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0); glVertex2d(-1.0,-1.0);
            glTexCoord2d(1.0,0.0); glVertex2d(+1.0,-1.0);
            glTexCoord2d(1.0,1.0); glVertex2d(+1.0,+1.0);
            glTexCoord2d(0.0,1.0); glVertex2d(-1.0,+1.0);
        glEnd();

        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, rightImage );

        glBegin( GL_QUADS );
            glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0); glVertex2d(-1.0,-1.0);
            glTexCoord2d(1.0,0.0); glVertex2d(+1.0,-1.0);
            glTexCoord2d(1.0,1.0); glVertex2d(+1.0,+1.0);
            glTexCoord2d(0.0,1.0); glVertex2d(-1.0,+1.0);
        glEnd();

        glPopMatrix();
        glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

        SwapBuffers( hDC );
    }
}

// free the texture
FreeTexture( leftImage );
FreeTexture( rightImage );

// shutdown OpenGL
DisableOpenGL( hWnd, hDC, hRC );

// destroy the window explicitly
DestroyWindow( hWnd );

return msg.wParam;
```

As long i've tried, i'm sure the code doesn't work well at here:

```
glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_LEFT);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_RIGHT);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// setup texture mapping
glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, leftImage );

glPushMatrix();

glBegin( GL_QUADS );
    glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0); glVertex2d(-1.0,-1.0);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0,0.0); glVertex2d(+1.0,-1.0);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0,1.0); glVertex2d(+1.0,+1.0);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0,1.0); glVertex2d(-1.0,+1.0);
    glEnd();

glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, rightImage );

    glBegin( GL_QUADS );
        glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0); glVertex2d(-1.0,-1.0);
        glTexCoord2d(1.0,0.0); glVertex2d(+1.0,-1.0);
        glTexCoord2d(1.0,1.0); glVertex2d(+1.0,+1.0);
        glTexCoord2d(0.0,1.0); glVertex2d(-1.0,+1.0);
    glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

SwapBuffers( hDC );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check that the pixelformat actually chosen does support stereo? Unfortunately, due to political/marketing and not technical reasons, consumer grade GPUs from both NVidia and AMD don't support quadbuffer stereo. So it's likely that the pixelformat you got back doesn't support it as well. Hence the right eye framebuffer won't be available in that case.

#### Update

In addition to that: Where do you set in which framebuffer you want to actually render?

It should look something like this:

```
glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK);  // <<<< enable both back buffers for clearing
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// setup texture mapping
glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

glPushMatrix();

glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, leftImage );
glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_LEFT); // <<<< enable left back buffer to draw left image to
glBegin( GL_QUADS );
    glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0); glVertex2d(-1.0,-1.0);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0,0.0); glVertex2d(+1.0,-1.0);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0,1.0); glVertex2d(+1.0,+1.0);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0,1.0); glVertex2d(-1.0,+1.0);
glEnd();


glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, rightImage );
glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_RIGHT); // <<<< enable left back buffer to draw right image to
glBegin( GL_QUADS );
    glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0); glVertex2d(-1.0,-1.0);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0,0.0); glVertex2d(+1.0,-1.0);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0,1.0); glVertex2d(+1.0,+1.0);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0,1.0); glVertex2d(-1.0,+1.0);
glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

SwapBuffers( hDC );
```

Comment: I have tried on supported quad buffer graphic card(tested with the Quadro 4000, Quadro 600, Quadro FX 3500) it's work well using gali-3d sample(red blue) www.gali-3d.com/archive/articles/StereoOpenGL/StereoscopicOpenGLTutorial.php. That sample not using raster data, so I try to implement something similar(stereo) with raster data, but the result is only one image displayed. (using the code above).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your code working fine. Now two images can be displayed (stereo).
So the concultion, we need to use glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK) and glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) before we use glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_LEFT) and glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_RIGHT), then we must begin glBegin (GL_QUADS) to display its images. That's right?

Comment: @respeto14: You could in fact call glClear twice, once for each side. One thing you have to understand is, that OpenGL is a state based drawing machine, that merely puts (textured/shaded) points, lines and triangles into a pixel framebuffer. It's not some automagic scene graph. When you call `glDrawBuffer(…)` everthing after that will be drawn to the specified buffer. Until you make the next call to `glDrawBuffer(…)`, which switches the state for everything after. There's no specific rule what to do in which order. What matters is, that when drawing something OpenGL is in the right state.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll learn more about them. Basicly i'm newbe with openGL but i would like to try and learn.